# Getting the text between delimiters with regex

Tags: regex

How can I get the contents between two delimiters using a regular expression? For example, I want to get the stuff between two `|`. For example, for this input:

```
|This is the text I want|
```

it should return this:

```
This is what I want
```

I already tried `/^|(.*)$|/`, but that returns `This is what I want |` instead of just `This is what I want` (shouldn't have the `|` at the end)

Comment: Your second `|` should come before the `$`, not after it.

Comment: Along with what @senshin said, you should use the `^` and `$` boundaries only if you want it to find everything between the pipe at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Try escaping the pipes `/\|(.*?)\|/`

For example, using JavaScript:

```javascript
var s = '| This is what I want |';
var m = s.match(/\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|/);
m[1]; // => "This is what I want"
```

See example here:
https://regex101.com/r/qK6aG2/2